# How does one use /gazebo/spawn_sdf_model?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to delete and respawn an SDF model as a (hopeful) work around to my problem [here.](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5488/calling-gazeboreset_simulation-breaks-contact/)

I'd like to use a rosservice so I can call it using a rospy.ServiceProxy.

For now, I'm just trying to get it to run from the command line:

```
$ rosservice call /gazebo/spawn_sdf_model "model_name: 'joe'
model_xml: '/home/benb/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/WAMInProgress/tp/AllInOne/Trajectory_Phonebook/ros_stuff/src/iiim_wam_description/wam.sdf'
robot_namespace: ''
initial_pose:
  position: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}
  orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0}
reference_frame: ''"
```

I've tried using a few things for the model_xml argument:

- The above is the absolute path to the sdf.
- I've tried launching it from `/home/benb/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/WAMInProgress/tp/AllInOne/Trajectory_Phonebook/ros_stuff/src/iiim_wam_description/` with the argument  `model_xml: 'wam.sdf'`
- I've tried using the directory name `iiim_wam_description`
- I've tried using the name specified in the model.config, `iiim_ros_wam`

In all cases, I get the message:

```
success: False
status_message: GazeboRosApiPlugin SpawnModel Failure: input model_xml not SDF or URDF, or cannot be converted to Gazebo compatible format.
```

It would be especially helpful if someone could give me pointers on doing this using the rospy ServiceProxy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5553/how-does-one-use-/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model-?/) by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 175 on 2014-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Got it. The answer is that the SDF argument is not a location to an SDF file -- it's the whole content of the SDF file.

To access this in rospy, you can do this:

```
import rospy
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnModel
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose


rospy.init_node('insert_object',log_level=rospy.INFO)

initial_pose = Pose()
initial_pose.position.x = 1
initial_pose.position.y = 1
initial_pose.position.z = 1

f = open('/home/benb/Dropbox/RoboticsResearch/WAMInProgress/tp/AllInOne/Trajectory_Phonebook/ros_stuff/src/iiim_wam_description/wam.sdf','r')
sdff = f.read()

rospy.wait_for_service('gazebo/spawn_sdf_model')
spawn_model_prox = rospy.ServiceProxy('gazebo/spawn_sdf_model', SpawnModel)
spawn_model_prox("some_robo_name", sdff, "robotos_name_space", initial_pose, "world")
```

---

Originally posted by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) with karma: 175 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2